# Service to keep variables in memory

Tags: beginner, c, linux

I'm a beginner C programmer. I want to write a program with the following characteristics:

1. The program is essentially a 'daemon' or a 'service' that sits in the background doing nothing except maintaining a variable value in memory.
2. Once a program that queries the saved values is executed, the background program should return the saved value.
3. Executing a program that is able to edit the value of the variable changes the value saved in the memory.

I wrote a program in my Ubuntu box (I want it to run in a Linux environment) using named pipes and pthreads. The background program is as follows:

**manager.c**

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

char a = 'a';

void *editTask(void *dummy)
{
    int fd;
    int bytes;
    char* editor = "editor";
    int ret = mkfifo(editor, 0666);
    if(ret < 0)
        perror("manager: creating pipe to read input data.");
    while(1)
    {
        fd = open(editor, O_RDONLY);
        if(fd < 0)
            perror("manager: opening pipe to read input data.");
        bytes = read(fd, &a, 1);
        if(bytes == 0)
            printf("manager: nothing read when trying to read input data\n");
        else if(bytes < 0)
            perror("manager: reading from input data pipe.");
        ret = close(fd);
        if (ret < 0)
            perror("manager: closing the pipe after reading input data");
    }   
}

void *readTask(void *dummy)
{
    int fd;
    int bytes;
    char* reader = "reader";
    int ret = mkfifo(reader, 0666);
    if(ret < 0)
        perror("manager: creating pipe to write current value.");
    while(1)
    {
        fd = open(reader, O_WRONLY);
        if(fd < 0)
            perror("manager: opening pipe to write current value.");
        bytes = write(fd,&a,1);
        if(bytes == 0)
            printf("manager: nothing written when trying to write the current value\n");
        else if(bytes < 0)
            perror("manager: writing the current value to write pipe.");
        ret = close(fd);
        if(ret < 0)
            perror("manager: closing the pipe after writing current variable value");       
    }
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t editor_thread, reader_thread;
    int ret;
    ret = pthread_create(&editor_thread, NULL, editTask, NULL);
    if(ret < 0)
        printf("manager: creating thread for editor thread failed. Error no:%d\n",ret);
    ret = pthread_create(&reader_thread, NULL, readTask, NULL);
    if(ret < 0)
        printf("manager: creating thread for reader thread failed. Error no:%d\n",ret);
    ret = pthread_join (editor_thread, NULL);
    if(ret < 0)
        printf("manager: joining thread for editor thread failed. Error no:%d\n",ret);
    ret = pthread_join (reader_thread, NULL);
    if(ret < 0)
        printf("manager: joining thread for reader thread failed. Error no:%d\n",ret);
    return 0;
}
```

The reader program is as follows:

**read.c**

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int fd;
    int ret;
    char * myfifo = "reader";
    fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
    if(fd < 0)
        perror("read: opening pipe");
    char value = 'z';
    ret = read(fd, &value, 1);
    if(ret == 0)
        printf("read: nothing read\n");
    else if(ret < 0)
        perror("read: reading from file");
    printf("The current value of the variable is:%c\n",value);      
    ret = close(fd);
    if(ret < 0)
        perror("read: closing pipe");
    return 0;
}
```

The writer program is as follows:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
    printf("Need an argument!\n");
    return 0;
    }           
    int fd;
    int ret;
    char * myfifo = "editor";
    fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
    if(fd < 0)
        perror("write: opening pipe to write");
    ret = write(fd, argv[1], 1);
    if(ret == 0)
        printf("write: nothing written to pipe\n");
    else if (ret < 0)
        perror("write: writing to pipe");       
    ret = close(fd);
    if(ret < 0)
        perror("write: closing the pipe");
    return 0;
}
```

So far, so good the program is working. However, this program will be a crucial part of a bigger program that should be very reliable. I have a feeling that usage of named pipes is not a very reliable method. I do not have much experience in programming. So I'd like to have your opinion on it. Apart from a possible race condition, do you think this is a bad approach for the problem? If it is, then what approach do you think I should take?

Comment: These programs already exist. They are called "Data Bases". Install MySQL on your box and store and retrieve your variables from the MySQL service.

Comment: If you want to build it your self you should look up how to create a socket. The look up protocols (REST is a good one). You can then make standard HTTP requests to look up/store/edit variables.

Comment: @LokiAstari the whole purpose of the program is to hold a variable (would be a multi-dimensional array or a structure in the real program) and update a value at a specific index and return a value at a specific index. Nothing else. No  Do I really need a database for this purpose?

Comment: This is what a DB does. You can write your own service (that is a lot simpler) but it will never be as good as one that already exists (and has been tested).

Comment: If you really need to store data persistenly in memory, I would recommend saving it to a memory-mapped file. The program that needs it can then map the file to memory with `mmap()`, read it, and update it.

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts:

- The first thing I noticed about your server code is that you don't seem to [detach yourself from the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8777602/592182), is this intentional?
- I'm not a huge fan of FIFO's.  There's no real reason for it, other than I generally prefer to use either sockets (particularly if remote access is required), or [shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5656561/592182) if I need to communicate large amounts of data locally.
- You main in manager.c is attempting to `join`, however your read/write loops don't have terminating conditions other than an error being encountered.
- The data you're allowing to be viewed / manipulated is called 'a'.  This seems like a rather understated variable name for such a key element of the program.
- This line really doesn't read well to me:

  ```
  fd = open(reader, O_WRONLY);
  ```

  Open *reader* for write only.  It feels like the variable name is wrong.

Comment: I didn't know about detaching. I'd look into it, thanks. I decided that I'd go for sockets. However, remote access is not required. I realize join statements are not useful. Thanks. This is a toy program written just to demo the concept, not the real one. So the variable name is rather random. I named the variable 'reader' because the outside programs see the pipe as a stream to read from. Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 1):

### Use the Right Kind of Inter-Process Communication

If you need to store data persistently and load it into memory, you can save it to a memory-mapped file, map it into another process’ memory with `mmap()`, and read and update the value.  There is no need to keep a daemon alive just to remember the value.

If you need two processes to share memory while both are active, you can use a shared-memory segment and attach it with `shmat()`.

If multiple processes need to read the value simultaneously, it should be stored as an atomic variable and accessed through that API.